# Xcode navigation bar item disappears when connect to main view to show

Tags: swift, xcode

When I Embed Navigation controller to MainView and I make new ViewController.

So I Have Two ViewController(A,B). I insert new navigation bar in B and also insert button in B new navigationbar.

I drag new button to B swiftFile and I rename Save Button

```
@IBAction Save(_ sender : Any){

}
```

And I also set B new Button control+drag -> A Controller -> Show

After that, B Save Button disappear but that is working well but Save Method does not work.

I want when I press Save button in Save method process

```
UserDefault.standard.set(information)
```

and get information on A Controller.

I almost make that process but Save button does not work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this step:

**Step1 :**

Add `navigationController` before `Class A`. Add your `Show button`.

**Step2:**
In `Show button action` write

```
let yourViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewControllerId") as? yourViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourViewController!, animated: true)
```

**Step3:**
Add Save button in `class B`. In `Save button` action please write :

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(information, forKey: "information")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

**Step4:**

Then you will get the value in `ViewWillAppear` method in `class A`

It may helps you. Thank you.

Comment: please accept my answer by click the tick mark and upvote my answer by click the up arrow. So that other user can get help form this answer. Thank you